# Getting annotation value of generic interface in java

Tags: java, generics, annotations

I am trying to get the annotation values.  This is my scenario as follows:

This is the annotation I declared.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
 public @interface PluginMessage {
 String name();
 String version();
}
```

This is the class the uses the annotation for some values

```
@PluginMessage(name = "RandomName", version = "1")
public class Response{
 private Date Time;
}
```

This is a generic interface which will be used in the next code snippet.

```
public interface ResponseListener<E> {
  void onReceive(E response);
}
```

I Invoke this by calling the following code:

```
  addListener(new ResponseListener<Response>() {
      @Override
      public void onReceive(Response response) {
        System.out.println();
      }
  });
```

This is the implementation of the addListener method:

```
public <E> void addListener(ResponseListener<E> responseListener) {
    Annotation[] annotations = responseListener.getClass().getAnnotations();

}
```

The annotations are always empty, any idea of what I am doing wrong?  I am trying to get the value of them here.

Comment: ResponseListener has no annotations on it - Response does, and there is no relationship between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may get annotations here:

```
.addListener(new ResponseListener<Response>() {
        public void onReceive(Response response) {
            final Annotation[] annotations = response.getClass().getAnnotations();
            for (Annotation annotation : annotations) {
                System.out.println("annotation.toString() = " + annotation.toString());
            }
        }
    });
```

Your `.addListener` implementation makes no sense. Instead of getting annotations from `ResponseListener`(which has no annotations) instance, you have to add listener to listeners pool. Then you have to call `listener.onReceive(...)` for each listener when you will receive the response. I believe something like that should be implemented there.

Comment: Notice that @Andrej has changed the `.getAnnotations()` call to call it on the `Response` class and not on the `ResponseListener`. This is the key to correcting your issue.